# Why can two user accessing the same variable within my REST API

Tags: javascript, node.js, spotify

I'm currently working on a Spotify API project and I come to a strange behavior which I can't explain to me.

Here is my Code to which I'm now referring to:

```
app.post("/get-spotify-data", async (req, res) => {
  var spotifyApi = new SpotifyWebApi();

  spotifyApi.setAccessToken(req.body.accessToken);

  await spotifyApi.getMyCurrentPlayingTrack().then(
    function (data) {
      if (data.body.item) {
        artists_names = [];

        data.body.item.artists.forEach((artist) => {
          artists_names.push(artist.name);
        });

        youtube
          .search(data.body.item.name + data.body.item.artists[0].name)
          .then((results) => {
            res.json({
              track_name: data.body.item.name,
              album_cover: data.body.item.album.images[0].url,
              artists: artists_names.join(","),
              link: results.videos[0].link,
            });
          });
      }
    },
    function (err) {
      console.log("Something went wrong!", err);
    }
  );
});
```

So the strange behavior is that when two users call the URL "/get-spotify-data" from my Front-End at the same time (the function get's called every second) then the both users get alternately the artists from his song and the artists from the song of the other user is listening to. But the other values get sent correctly.

Might this have to do something with that I declared the artists variable? I thought as long as I won't declare it outside the function, it won't affect multiple calls.

Comment: You didn't scope the variable to the function, so it's a global, i.e. shared with the whole script / all requests. Use `var / let / const`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I forgot to scope the variable.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).